# Java and SetWindowDisplayAffinity

Tags: java, winapi, screen-scraping, jna

I am using jna.extra.User32Extra library and I have to change windowdisplayaffinity value.
Unfortunately the output is always false, I don't know why, and this code doesn't work. I expect WDA_MONITOR makes windows black when print screen

```
public class Browser extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        WebView view = new WebView();

        WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://google.com");
        pane.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1280, 720);
        stage.setTitle("Browser JAVA");        
        stage.setScene(scene);

        WinDef.HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, "");
        boolean output = User32Extra.INSTANCE.SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd, 1); 
        System.out.println("output "+output);//false

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your window isn't a top window, as the documentation suggests:

> it returns FALSE when, for example, the function call is made on a non top-level window.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity

You should do as the doc says:

> To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/d852e148-985c-416f-a5a7-27b6914b45d4).